# Escape the double quotes in css inline style in php echo

Tags: php, html, css

I am sorry if this is duplicated but I could not find an answer to this situation. I am trying to escape the double quotes from the inline style in the PHP code.

```
<?php if (isset($ioTitle)){
    echo "<div style='background-color: echo $params->get('colorbgt'); ;' class=\"ioTitleBox\"><h3 class=\"ioTitle\">";
    echo $params->get("ioTitle"); echo "</h3></div>"; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: @HassanALi His confusion is more complicated than that.

Comment: yes it ispossible duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put `echo` inside a string and expect it to be executed. You need to use concatenation.

```
echo "<div style='background-color: " . $params->get('colorbgt') . ";' class=\"ioTitleBox\"><h3 class=\"ioTitle\">";
```

You don't need to escape anything in the style for this. Also, you can use single quotes around the classes, to avoid those escapes.

```
echo "<div style='background-color: " . $params->get('colorbgt') . ";' class='ioTitleBox'><h3 class='ioTitle'>";
```

Comment: I just got a lightbulb floating over my head. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (isset($ioTitle)){
        echo "<div style='background-color:". $params->get('colorbgt').";' class=\"ioTitleBox\"><h3 class=\"ioTitle\">";
        echo $params->get("ioTitle"); echo "</h3></div>"; 
                    }
```

Is this how you want it?

You are echo-ing from inside an echo, you just need to concatenate that part into the existing echo statement.